# How to load pdf file from \bin\x64\Release in a published WinForm Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, file, pdf

**What am I doing?** I want to add a help file to a Windows Forms application. I added the pdf to a folder in my project and set the property **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy Always**. This causes the file to be copied to the Debug and Release directories in the bin. This works perfectly on debug mode when I run the application.

**What's the problem?** This does not work on the production version. I am targeting x64 os only. The pdf is being copied to **bin/x64/Release** but it crashes when loading.

This is how I load the pdf

```
string filePath = @"HelpFiles\File.pdf";
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, filePath));
```

Any idea on how I can get the program to load the file on the production version?

Comment: Where do you install your program? Your code tries to load the PDF from a folder relative to the current location. Usually it is the folder where your program runs unless you have changed it. So it is **<yourprogramfolder>\helpfiles\file.pdf**

Comment: @Steve The program runs from this folder "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\CompanyName" but it doesn't work even if I hard code it

Comment: You just need to be sure that, relative at your run folder, there is a subfolder named HelpFiles with the File.pdf inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening your projects's properties, under ***Publish*** tab, open ***Application Files...*** and include your "***HelpFiles\File.pdf***"

Similar to this?[image]

And then try to publish it.

Edit: All files/programs that are being installed by ClickOnce should be included in the *Application Files...* and Build Action property of the pdf file from *None* to *Content*.

Comment: Yup you're right! It wasn't in the Application Files, and therefore not being installed with the program by ClickOnce. To included I just had to change the Build Action property of the pdf file from None to Content. If you include this in your answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works! I was thinking the reason why it is crashing on your production version is because you had a different os. Edited done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a fixed pdf file you could simply just add the file to your project as [ressource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx).
Then you will have access to the file as `Byte[]`. using

```
String tmpPdfFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), String.Format("{0}.pdf", Path.GetTempFileName()));
File.WriteAllBytes(tmpPdfFilePath, Properties.Default.PdfFile);
Process.Start(tmpPdfFilePath);
```

Only downside, you copy the file to the `temp` dir every time. You could get around this by using a static filename instead of `Path.GetTempFile()`. Check if the file exists and copy it to the temp on demand.

### Update

If you add the file as ressource to your project in the default ressource file you can get the bytes of the file with

```
Properties.Resources.FileName
```

Comment: I am going to try it. What is Path.GetTempFile(), the file name in the resources?

Comment: Oh, typo sorry. I'll update the answer i ment `Path.GetTempFileName()`. This just gets a file name for a temp file from windows check  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also not sure about Properties.Default.PdfFile. The overloads from the WriteAllText method take either a byte[], string[], string or IEnumerable<string>

Comment: I've written this from memory, I'm curently nowhere near a visual studio. If you add the file with the link provided it should be something like `Properties.Default.FileName` or `Properties.Ressources.Filename`. I'll check this in the office tomorrow and update my answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I already solved the issue but you should still edit the answer I think. It's always good to see different approaches